# Receiving continuous data using 32feet in .Net (BLUETOOTH)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bluetooth, 32feet

I am creating a Windows Form application, where it is connecting to a device through bluetooth. I am able to send commands to the device and I am receiving the data continuously. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to show the continuous data in the text box. The text box only shows the first line of characters the application is receiving. Here is my code:

CONNECT BUTTON ACTION:

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            lblProgress.Text = "";

            btnStart.Enabled = true;

            cBoxAvailablePorts.Enabled = cBoxAvailableBaudRates.Enabled = true;

            try
            {
                int pos = listBox.SelectedIndex;

                deviceInfo = array.ElementAt(pos);

                if (pairDevice())
                {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(() => connectThread());
                    thread.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Pair failed!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please connect to a device!");
        }
    }
```

THREAD ACTION

```
private void connectThread()
    {
        //BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
        bc.BeginConnect(deviceInfo.DeviceAddress, serviceClass, this.connectCallBack, bc);
    }
```

CALLBACK ACTION:

```
private void connectCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        //BluetoothClient client = (BluetoothClient)result.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            if (bc.Connected)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not able to identify Bluetooth devices! Please try again.!");
        }
    }
```

START BUTTON ACTION:
Here I send a command "S".
In button action I call sendMessage("S").
The function that is called is shown below:

```
public void sendMessage(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            if (bc.Connected)
            {
                Stream stream = bc.GetStream();

                stream.ReadTimeout = 1000;

                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);

                streamWriter.WriteLine(msg);

                streamWriter.Flush();

                // Read operation

                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);

                string result = streamReader.ReadLine();

                txtResult.Text = result;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sending failed!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I wrote the StreamReader part in a loop, and it gave me Socket Exception.
I also tried to get the data from Serial Port and used DataReceived event just in case, but still it didn't help.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

OKAY! I solved the problem. Without getting in trouble with 32feet library (though it is fun to code with 32feet), I thought to make communication through serial port. I connected the device with my laptop and got to know the outgoing COMPORT in bluetooth setting of my laptop. The two-way communication can only be done through outgoing COMPORT, not the incoming COMPORT.

Suppose the outgoing COMPORT is COM12 and the baud rate that I have set is 9600.
So here is my code:

```
public delegate void updateDelegate(string text);

private updateDelegate objDelegate;

private SerialPort serialPort;

public View() // constructor
{
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.objDelegate = new updateDelegate(getText);

        serialPort = new SerialPort("COM12", 9600);
        serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
        serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
}
```

START BUTTON ACTION

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sendData("S");
    }
```

// SEND COMMAND

```
    public void sendData(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort.Open();

                //serialPort.Close();
            }

            if (serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort.Write(msg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

// READ DATA

```
    public void readData()
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string res = serialPort.ReadExisting();

        Thread.Sleep(500);

        txtResult.Invoke(this.objDelegate, new object[] {res});
    }

    public void getText(string text)
    {
        txtResult.Text = text;
    }
```

I hope this will help someone! Thank you!!!